# Adding Two Large Numbers Using Stacks

Tags: java, stack

I'm trying to make a program that can add large numbers out of the ordinary like 8,330,103,343,234 and 5,123,342,345,231 or any numbers based on user input. That is just a radical example. My issues  aside from implementing the stack class are I'm not entirely too sure on how to get the user input numbers into a stack as a **string**. I do know that I'll have to make use of two stacks and possibly a third one to hold the remainder of the numbers.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `BigInteger` class?

Comment: I suggest you try this and see how you go. I would write a methof which reads a number and returns a stack.  Then you can write a method which adds the numbers in two stacks together and returns another stack and finally one which prints the result.

Comment: can you add few integers from a stack ?? IF yes then all you need to do is - replace Integer class with BigInteger

Comment: Please read the help->tour, especially the part about question not having chit-chat on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how you are handling user input, but the following might get you started in simple linear fashion (just an example):

```
Stack<BigInteger> stack = new Stack<BigInteger>();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter number: ");
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(scan.next().trim());
stack.push(bi);
System.out.print("Enter number: ");
bi = new BigInteger(scan.next().trim());
stack.push(bi);
System.out.println(stack.pop().add(stack.pop()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Here's a simple example:

```
BigInteger num1 = BigInteger.valueOf(8330103343234);
BigInteger num2 = BigInteger.valueOf(5123342345231);
BigInteger sum = num1.add(num2);
```